# Naming or Re-naming a Local Yum Repository

Tags: repository, yum

Is there a way to specify the name of a repository from the command line? I know that you can just pop in a file to `/etc/yum.repos.d/<name>.repo>` with the name you want, but I would prefer to use the interface before resorting to that.

Currently I call

```
>> yum-config-manager --add-repo file:///path/to/local/repo
```

which creates a file like `/etc/yum.repos.d/path_to_local_repo.repo` with a section heading of `path_to_local_repo` and a name like "added from file:///path/to/local/repo". Is there a way to do this using some other command (currently I only know of `yum-config-manager` to do these kinds of things.)

What I am really wanting this for is to have the ability to delete a repository programmatically, and I don't want to guess at the repo name.

Comment: The repo you are adding presumably doesn't already have a `.repo` file of its own somewhere you can point to instead of the repo directory?

Comment: In the end I think I am just going to have to create my own `.repo` file. Then I can at least control what the name and repo id are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at `http://yum.baseurl.org/gitweb?p=yum-utils.git;a=blob;f=yum-config-manager.py;h=380a54fd89b8d2f1afc96020be20d231733b838b;hb=HEAD` certainly seems to indicate that you can't control those fields when you use `yum-config-manager` in this mode.

If you can find (or create) a .repo file that has the contents you want then you can use `yum-config-manager` in that mode and it looks like it should use the file you gave it directly.

Comment: It appears as though creating a .repo file is the only way to do this.